# AngularJS child div not being animated when ng-class is on parent div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a group of elements that look like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="showcasePane" ng-class="state.current.name">
            <div class="contentPane" ui-view></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When `ng-class` is not present on `showcasePane` then `contentPane` is animated as expected (with enter/leave animations), however when `ng-class` is present `contentPane` no longer animates and instead only `showcasePane` does (as in, it gets `-active` suffixes added to the adding/removing classes) -- even though I do not want it to.

How can I get `contentPane` to animate when `ng-class` is present on the parent div?

Comment: Can you set up a quick fiddle?

Comment: [This](http://plnkr.co/edit/mqJuAV?p=preview) is with ng-class and [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtGITI?p=preview) is using ng-style (where it works correctly)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was related to several issues the stable Angular version(1.2) had, moving to the latest(beta-7) has fixed my problems though I am not entirely sure what the true causes were.

I suspect they were related to these now fixes issues:

[ngAnimate clobbers ngClass](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4949)

[ngClass with ngAnimate breaks existing css transitions](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6674)